# Why CrossBrowser Automated Script Throws Error in Edge Browser?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

*Guys i Was Doing Cross Browser Automation in Chrome, FireFox  and Edge . I Cant Able To Complete The Test Script in Edge Browser. I Was Getting an Error Message*

```
"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 42 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
    System info: host: 'rcktechiess-06', ip: '192.168.1.44', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, InPrivate=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, acceptSslCerts=true, browserVersion=42.17134.1.0, platformVersion=10, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows}]
    Session ID: B339099D-F7C6-41A7-A6E6-12D22C3D9937
```

[I Have Attched Image For Exception. Please Check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJZn3.jpg)

```
**Test 1 Code Using Testng**

package Crossbrowser;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test1 {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest

    @Parameters("browser")

    public void setup(String browser) throws Exception
    {
        //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
        {
        //create firefox instance

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'

        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            //set path to chromedriver.exe

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");

            //create chrome instance

            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        //Check if parameter passed as 'Edge'

                else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge"))
                {
                    //set path to IE.exe

                    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","F:\\New folder (2)\\MicrosoftWebDriver (1).exe");
                    //create Edge instance

                    driver = new EdgeDriver();

                }
        else
        {
            //If no browser passed throw exception

            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test

    public void testParameterWithXML() throws InterruptedException
    {

        driver.get("http://xxxxxxxxxx/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/header[1]/ss-header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/a[1]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //Find user name
        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ss-auth-form[1]/md-card[1]/ss-login-form[1]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]"));
        //Fill user name
        userName.sendKeys("koushick@rcktechiees.com");
        //Find password
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ss-auth-form[1]/md-card[1]/ss-login-form[1]/div[1]/form[1]/input[2]"));
        //Fill password
        password.sendKeys("1234567890");

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='myForm']//ss-submit-button[@label='Log In']//input[@class='submit']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Test2 obj = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Test2.class);

         Thread.sleep(2000);

         try
         {
             Actions a1 = new Actions(driver);
             a1.moveToElement(obj.getE1()).click(obj.getE2()).build().perform();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println("Can't Click on The Elemnet");
         }

         Thread.sleep(2000);

         try
         {
         Actions a2 = new Actions(driver);
         a2.moveToElement(obj.getE3()).click(obj.getE3()).build().perform();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println("Can't Click");
         }

         Thread.sleep(2000);

         try
         {
             Actions a3 = new Actions(driver);
             a3.moveToElement(obj.getE4()).click(obj.getE5()).build().perform();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println("Can't Click on The Elemnet");
         }

         Thread.sleep(2000);

         obj.getE6().sendKeys("ss@gmail.com");

         Thread.sleep(2000);

         obj.getE7().click();

         Thread.sleep(2000);

         obj.getE8().click();

         Thread.sleep(2000);


       driver.navigate().to("http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/");

       Thread.sleep(2000);

       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@classname='nav-link men']")).click();

       Thread.sleep(2000);

        }


    @AfterTest
    public void MatchitnowWithXML() throws InterruptedException
    {

        Test2 obj1 = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Test2.class);

         Actions a4 = new Actions(driver);
          a4.moveToElement(obj1.getE9()).click(obj1.getE9()).build().perform();

          Thread.sleep(2000);

          obj1.getE10().click();

          Thread.sleep(2000);

          obj1.getE11().click();

          Thread.sleep(2000);

          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
          js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.id("sylnk-it")), 500);

          Thread.sleep(2000);

          obj1.getE12().click();

          Thread.sleep(2000);

          Actions a5 = new Actions(driver);
          a5.moveToElement(obj1.getE13()).click(obj1.getE13()).build().perform();

          Thread.sleep(2000);

          try
          {
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='cal-sly']")).click();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println("Not Visible To Click");
          }

          Thread.sleep(2000);

          driver.navigate().back();

          Thread.sleep(2000);

          driver.navigate().back();

          Thread.sleep(2000);

          try
          {
          Actions a6 = new Actions(driver);
          a6.moveToElement(obj1.getE14()).click(obj1.getE15()).build().perform();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println("Can't Move To The Element and Click");
          }

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        try
        {
            Actions a7 = new Actions(driver);
            a7.moveToElement(obj1.getE16()).click(obj1.getE17()).build().perform();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Can't Click on the Element !");
        }

        Thread.sleep(3000);

          JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
          jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)"); 

          Thread.sleep(1000);

          try
          {
              Actions a8 = new Actions(driver);
              a8.moveToElement(obj1.getE18()).click(obj1.getE19()).build().perform();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println("Can't Move To The Element and Click");
          }

          Thread.sleep(2000);



        try
        {

            Actions a9 = new Actions(driver);
            a9.moveToElement(obj1.getE20()).click().build().perform();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Can't Click");
        }

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        try
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/ss-app[1]/ss-search-page[1]/div[2]/ss-search-filters[1]/ss-slide-filter[1]/ss-search-filter[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]")).click();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Can't Click");
        }




    }


    }
```

*Down  am Attaching Page ObjectModel Framework Code*

```
**Test2 Code Using POM Framework Using GET Method**

    package Crossbrowser;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class Test2 {

    public WebElement getE1() {
        return e1;
    }

    public WebElement getE2() {
        return e2;
    }

    public WebElement getE3() {
        return e3;
    }

    public WebElement getE4() {
        return e4;
    }

    public WebElement getE5() {
        return e5;
    }


    public WebElement getE6() {
        return e6;
    }

    public WebElement getE7() {
        return e7;
    }


    public WebElement getE8() {
        return e8;
    }

     public WebElement getE9() {
        return e9;
    }

    public WebElement getE10() {
        return e10;
    }

    public WebElement getE11() {
        return e11;
    }

    public WebElement getE12() {
        return e12;
    }


    public WebElement getE13() {
        return e13;
    }

    public WebElement getE14() {
        return e14;
    }

    public WebElement getE15() {
        return e15;
    }

    public WebElement getE16() {
        return e16;
    } 

    public WebElement getE17() {
        return e17;
    }

    public WebElement getE18() {
        return e18;
    }

    public WebElement getE19() {
        return e19;
    }

    public WebElement getE20() {
        return e20;
    }



    @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/header[1]/ss-header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ss-user-dropdown[1]/div[1]/ss-svg-icon[1]/span[1]/i[1]")
    private WebElement e1;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/header[1]/ss-header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ss-user-dropdown[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[9]")
    private WebElement e2;


    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@id='ranomizeButton']")
    private WebElement e3;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html/body/div[2]/header/ss-header/div/div[2]/ss-user-dropdown/div")
    private WebElement e4;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html/body/div[2]/header/ss-header/div/div[2]/ss-user-dropdown/div/div/a[3]")
    private WebElement e5;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")
    private WebElement e6;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]")
    private WebElement e7;

    @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]")
    private WebElement e8;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html/body/div[2]/ss-app/ss-search-page/div[4]/div[2]/ss-products-list/div[2]/span[3]/ss-product-cell/div/div[4]/span")
     private WebElement e9;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html/body/div[2]/ss-app/div[6]/div/ss-auth-form/md-card/div[1]/span[1]/div/div[2]/label/span")
    private WebElement e10;


    @FindBy(id="C5")
    private WebElement e11;


    @FindBy(id="slynk_save")
    private WebElement e12;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/ss-app[1]/ss-header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]")
    private WebElement e13;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/ss-app[1]/ss-search-page[1]/div[4]/div[2]/ss-products-list[1]/div[2]/span[1]/ss-product-cell[1]/div[1]/div[5]")
    private WebElement e14;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/ss-app[1]/ss-search-page[1]/div[4]/div[2]/ss-products-list[1]/div[2]/span[1]/ss-product-cell[1]/div[1]/div[5]/a[2]/span[1]/i[1]")
    private WebElement e15;


    @FindBy(xpath="//ss-product-cell[@id='110743~Dresslily~womens-tops~womens-tops']//div[@class='product-cell-container extended-cell']//div[@class='bottom-icons']")
    private WebElement e16;


    @FindBy(xpath="//span[@id='~110743~Stylish Lace Embellished Short Sleeve Scoop Neck Womens TShirt~Dresslily~Dresslily~Dresslily~womens-tops~womens-tops~~undefined~$4.99~$9.67~~^^womens-tops^womens-clothes^women ']//i[@class='icon-12']")
    private WebElement e17;


    @FindBy(xpath="//ss-product-cell[@id='304028~GuessFactory~shorts~shorts']//div[@class='product-cell-container extended-cell']//div[@class='bottom-icons']")
    private WebElement e18;


    @FindBy(xpath="//span[@id='~304028~Shelby Denim Shorts~GuessFactory~Guess Factory~Guess Factory~shorts~shorts~~undefined~~$44.99~~^^shorts^womens-clothes^women ']//i[@class='icon-12']")
    private WebElement e19;


    @FindBy(xpath="/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/ss-app[1]/ss-search-page[1]/div[2]/ss-search-filters[1]/ss-slide-filter[1]/ss-search-filter[1]/span[1]")
    private WebElement e20;
```

PS: While Executing The Test Script are Sucessfully Passing in Chrome and FireFox. But Failing in Edge Only at The Middle of Automation Some Kind of Stack Error. Down Am Also Attching The XML Please Give Me a Solution To Find a BetterWay.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" >

  <test name="FirefoxTest">
  <parameter name="browser" value="firefox">
    <classes>
      <class name="Crossbrowser.Test1"/>
    </classes>
     </parameter>
     </test> <!-- Test -->

     <test name="chromeTest">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome">
    <classes>
      <class name="Crossbrowser.Test1"/>
    </classes>
     </parameter>
     </test> <!-- Test -->

      <test name="EdgeTest">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Edge">
    <classes>
      <class name="Crossbrowser.Test1"/>
    </classes>
     </parameter>
     </test> <!-- Test -->



</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: It's because of absolute xpath you are using , try to write css selector for all those. Then your script would be stable.

Comment: Okay.  @cruisepandey But i Have One Doubt , Using Abosolute Xpath Always Will Produce a Result Like This in Edge Browser?Why Am Asking Means Since the Scripts are Passing in Chrome and Firefox Why Can't Edge?

Comment: Because there is no native support for IE and edge from driver point of view. IE and Edge has to use 3rd -party library to get along with xpath. Where in case of chrome and FF , your driver have native support.

Comment: Fine , Now i got it. @cruisepandey Thanks For The Clear View. If You Got Some Other Points Also, Please Share With Me.

Comment: try to write css selector as they remain same across all the browser , I understand the scenario where you would have to write the xpath , in that case be bit relative rather than depending on absolute xpath.

Comment: Thanks Man, I Changed The Code Little Bit With CSS it Started Working Now. Thanks For The Solution Man @cruisepandey